# How to use child class as a key while converting to json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a parent class

```
public interface Country {    
}
```

And a child class

```
public class India implements Country {
    public String language;
}
```

In the main method, I wrote this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        India c = new India();
        c.language = "Hindi";
        Team a = new Team();
        a.setCountry(c);
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(a));
    }
```

**Output**

```
{"country":{"language":"Hindi"}}
```

Is there any way I can get output as below using gson

```
{"India":{"language":"Hindi"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do this when using Map, don't know any solution that can do the same with POJO approach. Maybe not what's exactly what you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    India c = new India();
    c.language = "Hindi";
    Map<String, Object> a = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    a.put(c.getClass().getSimpleName(), c);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(a));
}
//{"India":{"language":"Hindi"}}
```